# Angular 2 and DatePipe with milliseconds

Tags: angular

Why is 360000 Milliseconds shown as 01:06:00. It's only 6 minutes?
It also looks like it remembers the first date pipe result and add this value to the next.

```
<p>
  {{ unit.StartToday * 1000 | date: "HH:mm:ss"}}<br/>
  {{ unit.DrivingTimeToday * 1000 | date: "HH:mm:ss"}}
</p>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/46PdAjWsH5bk4KFIsvpV?p=preview

Comment: how you want it to be shown? **HH:mm:ss** converts it like that only

Answer (score 2):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html

> expression is a `date object` or a `number (milliseconds since UTC epoch)`
>   or an `ISO string`

this is 6 minutes, but your GMT is +1, so it'll display `01:06:00`. for me, GMT = +7 this app will print 07:06:00

[image: my time]